# How do we limit the maximum width and height of a canvas object in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kmvwz/).

I want to limit the maximum height/width of the object when you are resizing it.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/all.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="c" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
    <script>
      (function() {

         var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

         canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ width: 50, height: 50, fill: 'red', top: 100, left: 100 }));
         canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ width: 30, height: 30, fill: 'green', top: 50, left: 50 }));


      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>​
```

Comment: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/167#issuecomment-7010429 here it is said that we need to achieve it with events.. how do i do that?

Comment: Using `mousemove`, `mouseup` and `mousedown`.

Comment: say i want to set maximum heights to the red square and not the blue one from the above example. how do i do that? can you be more specific, how do i handle these mousemove event on a specific canvas object? @RicardoLohmann

Comment: @RicardoLohmann shouldn't the event be object:scaling from this link http://fabricjs.com/events/

Answer (score 9):

When scaling fabric Objects, the scaleX and scaleY properties are updated to reflect the new scaled size of the object. So the actual width of a rect with an initial width of 50 when scaled 2x will be 100.

What you need to do is figure out the maximum scale allowed for your shape given it's maxHeight or maxWidth. That's calculated by dividing the maximum dimension by the initial dimension.

Here's an example of how to implement maximum sizes for objects

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
var rect1  = new fabric.Rect({ width: 50, height: 50, fill: 'red',   top: 100, left: 100});
var rect2  = new fabric.Rect({ width: 30, height: 30, fill: 'green', top: 50,  left: 50 });

// add custom properties maxWidth and maxHeight to the rect
rect1.set({maxWidth:100, maxHeight:120});

canvas.observe("object:scaling", function(e){
    var shape        = e.target
    ,   maxWidth     = shape.get("maxWidth")
    ,   maxHeight    = shape.get("maxHeight")
    ,   actualWidth  = shape.scaleX * shape.width
    ,   actualHeight = shape.scaleY * shape.height;

    if(!isNaN(maxWidth) && actualWidth >= maxWidth){
        // dividing maxWidth by the shape.width gives us our 'max scale' 
        shape.set({scaleX: maxWidth/shape.width})
    }

    if(!isNaN(maxHeight) && actualHeight >= maxHeight){
        shape.set({scaleY: maxHeight/shape.height})
    }

    console.log("width:" + (shape.width * shape.scaleX) + " height:" + (shape.height * shape.scaleY));
});
```

Comment: How do you deal with the offset ?  Right now all the object resized are 10px larger than the max width/height that I provide

Comment: Hello @cyberpantz go through my question if possible : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500990/issue-with-object-while-restricting-it-to-canvas-boundary

Answer (score 2):

Works with most fabric objects.. but you want to get the ratio of your object, for maxWidth you can copy this... for maxHeight reverse it.

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(photo, function(image) {
  //console.log(image.width, image.height);
  var heightRatio = image.height / image.width;
  var maxWidth = 100;
  image.set({
    left: canvasDimensions.width / 2,//coord.left,
    top: canvasDimensions.height / 2, //coord.top,
    angle: 0,
    width: maxWidth,
    height: maxWidth * heightRatio
  })
  //.scale(getRandomNum(minScale, maxScale))
  .setCoords();

  canvas.add(image);
  })
```

Comment: You save my day!! Tks.