# Issue with object while restricting it to canvas boundary

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I am currently running with my project and in that i have used fabric js to work with canvas. In that i want my canvas object not to go out of canvas boundary.I did [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/8o4or49o/) and it is working fine unless and until i am rotating it. but when i am rotating the object, top left of that object is getting  as per rotation and my code is not working well. I want some solution which will work in any condition but my object should not go outside of canvas boundary.
Thanks

```js
var canvas=new fabric.Canvas('demo');
canvas.on('object:moving',function(e){
    if(e.target.getWidth()+e.target.left>canvas.width)
    {
        e.target.set('left',canvas.width-e.target.getWidth());
        e.target.setCoords();
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
    if(e.target.getHeight()+e.target.top>canvas.height)
    {
        e.target.set('top',canvas.height-e.target.getHeight());
        e.target.setCoords();
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
    if(e.target.top<0)
    {
        e.target.set('top',0);
        e.target.setCoords();
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
    if(e.target.left<0)
    {
        e.target.set('left',0);
        e.target.setCoords();
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
});
var text=new fabric.IText('Jayesh');
canvas.add(text);
```

```html
<script src="http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="demo" style="width:100px;height:100px;border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/gaz704v7/

```js
    var canvas=new fabric.Canvas('demo');
    canvas.on('object:moving', function (e) {
        var obj = e.target;
        // if object is too big ignore
        if(obj.currentHeight > obj.canvas.height || obj.currentWidth > obj.canvas.width) {
            return;
        }
        obj.setCoords();
        // top-left  corner
        if(obj.getBoundingRect().top < 0 || obj.getBoundingRect().left < 0) {
            obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top);
            obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left);
        }
        // bot-right corner
        if(obj.getBoundingRect().top+obj.getBoundingRect().height  > obj.canvas.height || obj.getBoundingRect().left+obj.getBoundingRect().width  > obj.canvas.width) {
            obj.top = Math.min(obj.top, obj.canvas.height-obj.getBoundingRect().height+obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top);
            obj.left = Math.min(obj.left, obj.canvas.width-obj.getBoundingRect().width+obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left);
        }
    });
    var text=new fabric.IText('Jayesh');
    canvas.add(text);
```

Comment: do one thing in your example,
1) scale an object to canvas width
2) rotate an object to 40 degree

you can see that object is going out of canvas boudary

Comment: @Innodel you need to decide what you want to do in that situation. For instance, take your object to be a square the same height and width of the canvas. It fits. When you rotate it, you could force it to scale down until it fits within the canvas boundary, but moving it anywhere within the canvas is simply not possible.